# Elasticsearch restore snapshot in a new single node cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I've made a snapshot using default settings:

`PUT /_snapshot/backup/%3Csnapshot-%7Bnow%2Fd%7D%3E?wait_for_completion=true`

Deleted old data, an tried to restore it on a new elasticsearch single node cluster:

`POST /_snapshot/backup/snapshot-2021.09.23/_restore`
, but I get error:

```
"type" : "snapshot_restore_exception",
"reason" : "[backup:snapshot-2021.09.23/esJtA1MeRcenJbz3tkIL2A] cannot restore index [.geoip_databases] because an open index with same name already exists in the cluster. Either close or delete the existing index or restore the index under a different name by providing a rename pattern and replacement name"
```

I want to do a simple snapshot restore... these guys at ES manage to over-complicate even a simple backup-restore operation.

I think the index in error is a system index. If so, can I restore my snapshot before system indexes are created?

How can I restore my snapshot?

*Elasticsearch 7.14.1*

---

I've also tried using:

```
POST /_snapshot/backup/snapshot-2021.09.23/_restore
{
  "include_global_state":false,
  "feature_states":[]
}
```

but the same error shows.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the error message it should be pretty clear:

> [backup:snapshot-2021.09.23/esJtA1MeRcenJbz3tkIL2A] cannot restore index [.geoip_databases] **because an open index with same name already exists** in the cluster. **Either close or delete the existing index** or restore the index under a different name by providing a rename pattern and replacement name"

So you have three choices:

A. Delete the index before doing the restore

```
DELETE index-name
POST /_snapshot/backup/snapshot-2021.09.23/_restore
```

B. Close the index before doing the restore and then it is reopened automatically after the restore operation is complete

```
POST index-name/_close
POST /_snapshot/backup/snapshot-2021.09.23/_restore
```

C. Restore the index under a different name

```
POST /_snapshot/backup/snapshot-2021.09.23/_restore
{
  "indices": "index-name",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false,              
  "rename_pattern": "(.+)",
  "rename_replacement": "$1_restored",
  "include_aliases": false
}
```

But since we're talking about a system index, it's a bit different, you need to proceed differently and restore the index via [feature states](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restore-snapshot-api.html#restore-snapshot-api-request-body):

```
POST /_snapshot/backup/snapshot-2021.09.23/_restore
{
  "feature_states":[ "geoip" ]
}
```

Adding flexibility for different use cases is not over-complicating :-)

Comment: `DELETE .geoip_databases` error: `illegal_argument_exception: Indices [.geoip_databases] use and access is reserved for system operations`. Same error for `close` op. More and more complicated :)

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand. Do you want to restore that index or just skip it because it's a system index and it's not allowed? What your goal?

Comment: I want to restore my single-node es instance state to the previously snapshot one. Backup-delete-restore.

Comment: So basically, delete everything then restore snapshot with global state and everything... just that you were able to delete all indices but the system indices. Am I correct?

Comment: I've created a new es instance with no data (no relation to old one), and want to restore my snapshot.

Comment: Ok, then the problem is that when starting the node, system indices get created when starting up the first time. Can you confirm that your empty cluster contains a few system indices using `GET _cat/indices`?

Comment: `green open .geoip_databases dRJ5r3YzRGG4KUn6NEzDLQ 1 0 43 0 40.7mb 40.7mb`, output shows the only culprit

Answer (score 0):

Opened github issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/78320

As a workaround I've managed to restore my snapshot by selecting the indices with wildcard so that it excludes the problematic system index:

```
POST /_snapshot/my_repository/snapshot_2/_restore?wait_for_completion=true
{
  "indices": "my-index-*,my-other-index-*",
}
```